# Is there an endless RPG system?

Tags: game-recommendation

Good day, everybody.

As already mentioned in the title, I'm looking for a RPG system, where there are no limitations on character's stats, allowing each player advance more and more, acquiring mastery in skills, learning new skills ad so on.

P.S.: I know, this is more likely a cRPG system than pen&paper, but, who knows? Maybe there is some p&p system like that.

P.P.S.: Thank's to all for the welcomes. You ask to be more specific... I'll try, but it's hard to express my thoughts straightly >_<

If this Q&A Service is only for Pen&Paper or Table Top RPG systems, then, well, close the question and forget about it. Cause for me the major target is some system, that can be used in the CRPG - a game for a PC/PS/Xbox/etc. But first, remember that D&D, the primordially Pen&Paper game, was used to make a really good game Neverwinter Nights.

I learned some number of different systems, like AD&D, D&D3.5, GURPS, Basic Fantasy RPG, 5 by 5, Synergy and others. Almost all of them are dice-based (that's not a problem) and they tend to give a player's character some basic stats from the begining, that can be "upgraded" only few times until the character reaches to some maximum level, set by DM. And at that point the evolution of the character ends.

One of the closest systems to my ideal is the one used in The Elder Scrolls series. There are some things I'd like to change, but in total it's really good. The other one system is the one used in browser-based MMO FallenSword. It's on the first look, but there are many pitfalls to inattentive players. Both those systems are kinda diceless (at least, for users, but who knows how are they made inside for real?), but that is not the point. Both of them allow player to evolve more and more.

But, both those systems have some minuses. TES has a limited world where enemies do not grow with you, becoming sooner or later too easy for you. FS has a quite simple system and lays prior stress to combat, ignoring peacefull variations of play, - almost every skill somehow effects combat.

So I would like to find some system, where you can start from nothing (or with some small basis, like in before named P&P systems) and become anything you want =^_^=

Sadly, the topic was closed and I was late for a minute with this answer to all. Thank you once more for your answers, I made some new conclusions and will continue searching and asking.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Here I thought this about the works of Neil Gaiman... Sadly, I think your question is trivially answered by *every system*.  What are you really looking for?

Comment: Could you be more specific about your intentions? I could come out with some systems but they are on the high-power side of the spectrum. Nobilis for example is a diceless system where you play a divine concept.

Comment: Welcome! I've voted to close your question as it seems to lack an understanding for just the depth and breadth of the table top RPG universe. You might see http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/how-to-deal-with-questions-that-just-dont-understand-the-scope-of-the-rpg-lands for some ideas on how to improve it.

Comment: Yes, we only do Table Top Pen&Paper games. You might try Game Dev, but you're probably going to need tighter requirements there as well. The issue is that you're asking for something that may be the mechanic of 100 different RPs and finding you one that suits your needs is virtually impossible (remember that there are a massive number of RPs out there with all sorts of mechanics and varying degrees of detail). Also if you're scope doesn't care whether it's table top or video game systems, you're not going to get what you need here.

Comment: I think that your question is a bit too open-ended to be answered.  What mastery means varies from system to system, depending on scale.  What are you looking to use the RPG system for, in terms of genre and power scale?  That would help to limit the question.  Ask specifically what you want to know that would practically help you solve a problem, and you're more likely to get questions that are specific to that problem.  Voted to close until this is cleared up.

Comment: GURPS character development doesn't end.

Answer (score 7):

Lots of P&P games do this. For a start, most points-based games impose no limits on a character's advancement. GURPS, Savage Worlds, and their ilk all allow a character to continue slowly advancing as long as player and GM interest holds.

Some level-based games allow this too. The Immortal rules for the Basic/Expert version of early D&D allowed (human) characters to advance indefinitely, albeit with some seriously flawed rules. [Dave Hargrin's Arduin Grimoire](http://jrients.blogspot.cz/2010/09/arduin-grimoire-part-3.html) offered essentially unlimited advancement, by expanding Original D&D's levels to 100. Example high-level ability for psychics: "At 50th level you gain the ability to explode people's heart with your brain."

Editions prior to 3rd, however, always limited the ability of non-human characters to advance forever. Basic/Expert D&D, for instance, capped Dwarves at level 12, Elves at level 10, and Halflings at level 8 (poor halflings!).

The 3.X edition of D&D allowed epic levels to go on more or less indefinitely for any race/class combination, [but with increasingly broken results](http://www.enworld.org/forum/d-d-legacy-discussion/58380-stacking-bonuses-3-5-a-3.html#post1056664). It's often been suggested that epic-level characters in D&D can walk off mountains with barely a scratch, or hide in bright sunlight in the middle of a crowded square.

The answer, then, is yes. Plenty of games allow endless advancement. However, in most level-based games like Dungeons & Dragons, the ultimate result is to break the game in half. The players end up being more powerful then any god, at which point DMing becomes something of a nightmare. Thus, for infinite advancement, you're probably better off with Savage Worlds, GURPS, or another point-based, slow-advancement system.

Comment: It has been a long long long time since I looked but aren't there race/class combinations that are forbidden in D&D?  Thus restricting what a character can do.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the system as much as with the nature of games. Even in a slow -advance system like GURPS, if you continue indefinitely (and successfully) adventuring with the same character you will eventually become more powerful than the government if not the gods: you're still using the same rulebook and character sheet, but you're not really playing 'the same game' as when you set out to find your fortune.

Comment: @TimLymington: That's certainly true, but I think D&D (particularly 3.5) "breaks" much more obviously then do slower systems. Epic-level D&D characters can punch through castle walls—a feat unavailable (so far as I know) to most higher-level GURPS PCs.

Comment: @Sardathrion not in newer editions

Comment: It should be added that 4e brought back an ultimate level cap, along with the built in notion that characters become something /else/ with their epic destiny, because of the realization that no system can support games going on for 20 years without making the first two or three boring and dangerous. +1 for pointing out the problems with games that go on and on.

Comment: @AncientToaster the Heroes manual for GURPS provides the point total for sufficient strength to punch Earth in half (About 900 points of STR with super-effort Strength) so I would have to disagree with you there.

Comment: @airza Um, but 900 points of ST is an absolutely insane amount, so unless you're playing super-hero game or some game world with some incredible buffing powers, it's nowhere near a practical possibility.